# Creating global variables - Java

Tags: java, global-variables

I am getting a compiling error for this code:

```
public class Matching {        
    public static int match = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*cities.size()); //Error is here
}
```

I'm want to make "match" a global variable.

My compiling error is:

> "Illegal static declaration in inner class testingProgram.Matching modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
>
> Usage of static non-final variable during initialization."

Don't know what the error means, nor do I know how to fix it.

Comment: If you don't plan to change the variable, add the `final` keyword before or after `static`.

Comment: What is cities variable? Your code is not clear, and it is not possible to test it.

Comment: cities is an arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your `Matching` class is located inside another class called `testingProgram`, and is not `static`.

Java allows `static` fields inside an inner class only when the inner class itself is `static`. You can fix this problem in several ways:

- By making `Matching` a `static` inner class,
- By making `Matching` a top-level class, or
- By making `static int match` final, i.e. `final static int match`

Comment: How do you know it is an inner class?

Answer (score 0):

Create the variable in some static class (main, for example) and make sure it gets passed to the constructor of this class. I don't know why you are doing this but the reason it's difficult is because it's not a good idea. If you need to save the state of 'match' then give more information.

```
public static void main() {
    int match;
    Matching m = new Matching(match);
}
```